# Why is member assignment being seen as Func<T, TReturn> and not Action<T>

Tags: c#, generics, fluent

I'm writing a fluent api for constructing business data concepts to setup integration and regression tests.

I have the following:

```
public AndWithContext<T> AndWith(Action<T> withAction)
    {
        withAction(_instance);
        return new AndWithContext<T>(_instance);
    }

public AndWithContext<TOut> AndWith<TOut>(Func<T, TOut> withContextChangeFunc)
    {
        var output = withFunc(_instance);
        return new AndWithContext<TOut>(output);
    }
```

and an example of how I imagine one would want to use the `Action<T>` portion of the api:

```
workOrder = c.Given<WorkOrder>()
                         .With(wo => wo.ReferenceNbr = 1234) 
                         .AndWith(wo => wo.SpecOrder = specOrder)
                         .AndWith(wo => wo.WorkItems = workItems)
                         .Create();
```

I'm expecting the call to `.AndWith(wo => wo.SpecOrder = specOrder)` to dispatch to the `AndWith(Action<T>)` but it's landing on `AndWith<TOut>(Func<T, TOut>)`

Yes, I know I can make it work as desired by telling users to write with the following convention when assigning property values inside the context:

```
workOrder = c.Given<WorkOrder>()
             .With(wo => wo.ReferenceNbr = 1234)
             .AndWith(wo => {
                              wo.SpecOrder = specOrder;
                              wo.WorkItems = workItems;
                              return wo;
                             })
             .Create();
```

But that's not the point.

Also interesting to me was that `(wo => {wo.SpecOrder = specOrder;})` routes to the correct overload, but removing the braces and semicolon suddenly makes this behave like `Func<T, TOut>`.

I'm sure this is happening for my `WithContext` signatures too, but calls to my with context are all context shifting calls and are purely for readability and the beginning of the statement, so I kinda don't care about those.

Comment: What happens if you use `T` instead of `TOut`?

Comment: `wo.SpecOrder = specOrder` returns the result of that assignment.

Comment: @Andy, I also have a "fluent" `Func<T, T>` signature, but the purpose of having the `Func<T, TOut>` is to guide the user to the new context that requires additional setup. If the author provides `AndWith` a func call that returns a different context component, that component needs additional setup before the author is returned to the original context and component types. `parent.With(p => p.Name = "josh").AndWith(p => p.BrotherName = "dave")` is invalid. I want them to say `parent.With(p => p.Name = "j").AndWith(p => p.GetChildren())` where `GetChildren` is an extension method for `Parent`.

Comment: a) Why doesn't the `AndWith<TOut>` not also define `T`?  b) Why is the implementation not symmetrical?  I would expect both to return an instance of `AndWithContext` with an `_instance` with the `TOut` implementation also providing the out value.  That you combine the two in different contexts seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: @KirkWoll The `T` is defined on the `WithContext<T>`. The `Func<T, TOut>` is effectively a context switch, but it's a context switch that uses the same context definition. I need the component to change because `Parent` sans `Child(ren)` is `Person`, so I want to change the context to a component that will make the author setup `Children` before allowing them to continue setting up the `Parent`.

Comment: I agree with @mjwills. The link was very helpful for understanding why it happens, and the need for it to route to the `Action<T>` is low. Downstream authors can code to the convention in tests.

Comment: Well, since this question was closed, here are my thoughts, @JoshGust:  https://imgur.com/a/c68Wr7M

Comment: That is a great suggestion, thanks for sharing it @KirkWoll.

Comment: @KirkWoll `.Create` is really only an exit point for the fluent path that returns the component `_instance` in the current context.

Comment: @JoshGust not totally following you.  I believe you are saying it returns either the original `_instance` or the `TOut` value.  Is that correct?   If so, wouldn't my proposed solution work in most scenarios?  (value types would be problematic)

Comment: This is fluent style creation, so the problem domain is vague and thus so are the context implementations.

Comment: To try and clarify the domain: the primary functions that are to be given to the context are predefined extensions on the `_instance`. Given that, i have some control over what the return value is representing (ie a new component that needs addl. setup). Access through the `Given, With, AndWith` and `Create` is not absolutely necessary, but it provides a measure of readability that would otherwise be lacking.